# Is it safe to remove zxcvbn.min.js from Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I see the file is located in Magento_customer and looks like it is being used for password validation or something. This file is close to 1 MB. Removing this could reduce the page size and can help speedup website. My combined JS is not around 1.5 MB. Would it be safe to just delete zxcvbn.min.js or is there a safer way to remove it?

Comment: It is script is using only in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/password-strength-indicator.js` (alias `passwordStrengthIndicator` in requireJs). If you don't use it in your design - it shouldn't loaded.

Comment: Hi Evgeny, I use Ultimo theme. How to not use in my theme? Please advice.

Comment: By default `passwordStrengthIndicator` using in customer edit form (`Magento_Customer/templates/form/edit.phtml`), register form (`Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml`) and forgotten password form (`Magento_Customer/templates/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml`). Remove `data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'` from this files in your theme, if you don't need this functionality.